# Asymptotics of polylogarithm $\mathrm{Li}_{-s}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s x^n$ as $x\to 1^-$

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

For $s>0$, let
$$\mathrm{Li}_{-s}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s x^n$$
be the polylogarithm function. It is convergent for $|x|<1$. As $x\to 1^-$, the series is divergent. What is the asymptotic behavior of $\mathrm{Li}_{-s}(x)$ as $x\to 1^-$?

Mathematica says that
$$\mathrm{Li}_{-s}(x) \approx  \frac{\Gamma(1+s)}{(1-x)^{1+s}}.$$
I want a proof of this result.

It is interesting that the Laplace transform of $t^{\alpha-1}$ has a similar form:
$$\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha} e^{-\beta t} dt = \frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\beta^{1+\alpha}}.$$

Comment: If you use the formula https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#E12, neglect the sum with the Riemann zeta function and Taylor expand around $z=1$ you obtain the same as Mathematica gives.

Comment: Using the Euler-Maclaurin formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)=\int_0^\infty f(t)dt+\frac{f(0)}2+R_1=\int_0^\infty f(t)dt+\frac{f(0)}2+\int_0^\infty f'(t)\big\{t-\frac12\big\}dt$$
For $f(t)=t^sx^t=t^xe^{-t\ln\frac1x}$, given that $f(0)=0$,
$$S=\int_0^\infty t^xe^{-t\ln\frac1x}dt+R_1=\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{(\ln\frac1x)^{s+1}}+R_1$$
where $$|R_1|<\frac{s\Gamma(s)}{(\ln\frac1x)^s}+\frac{\Gamma(s+1)\ln\frac1x}{(\ln\frac1x)^{s+1}}=O\left(\frac1{(\ln\frac1x)^s}\right)$$

Comment: Using $\,\ln\frac1x=(1-x)+O\big((1-x)^2\big)$
$$S=\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{(1-x)^{s+1}}+O\left(\frac1{(1-x)^s}\right)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thanks for your comment! Using Euler-Maclaurin formula is pretty elegant. I think this could be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand somewhat on the comment I provided, one has from [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#E12) that

$$
\text{Li}_{-s}(z) = \Gamma(1+s)\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{z} \right) \right)^{-s-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \zeta(-s-n) \frac{\ln^n(z)}{n!}.
$$

Around $z=1$, one then has that $\ln^n(z) \sim (z-1)^n$ and $\ln^{-s-1}(z^{-1}) \sim (1-z)^{-s-1}$ such that

$$
\text{Li}_{-s}(z) \sim \frac{\Gamma(1+s)}{(1-z)^{s+1}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \zeta(-s-n) \frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}.
$$

For $\zeta(-s-n)$, one may use the reflection formula to write

$$
\zeta(-s-n) = \frac{2\Gamma(s+n+1)}{(2\pi)^{s+n+1}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(s+n+1)\right)\zeta(s+n+1) 
$$

Hence,

$$
\text{Li}_{-s}(z) \sim \frac{\Gamma(1+s)}{(1-z)^{s+1}} + \frac{2}{(2\pi)^{s+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}\Gamma(s+n+1)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(s+n+1)\right)\zeta(s+n+1) 
$$

Each term in the sum decreases rapidly with increasing $n$ and to a first approximation, one arrives at

$$
\text{Li}_{-s}(z) \sim \frac{\Gamma(1+s)}{(1-z)^{s+1}}, \quad z\to 1^{-}
$$

as provided by Mathematica. In contrast to the terms inside the sum, this term is divergent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!